# Ion-img corrupted on Ionic 4

Tags: image, ionic4

I'm doing the following code but on my device just I can see a corrupted image without any information (even waiting a little bit to let the image load...), this is my code:

TypeScript

```
    goPhotoGallery() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 80,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      correctOrientation: true,
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
      // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
      let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.images = base64Image;
    }, (err) => {
      // Handle error
    });
```

HTML

```
    <ion-img [src]="images"></ion-img>
```

What should I do to display the image, also properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got resolved:

```
destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
```

instead of

```
destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
```

The End

Answer (score 0):

Use Brackets `{{images}}`

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-card>
    <img src="{{ images }}"  />
  </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```